# Views don't display any result until the exposed form is submitted

Tags: views

I have a view that display content on my website, but now (i don't know why) my view show results only when i submit the exposed form.

I would like my view display all result by default.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the matter !

I used a field in my view in the exposed form. But, after creating my view, I re-use this field in another content type with different label name.

Adding fact I use translation for this (taxonomy) field in my view too...

I simply **delete and re-create the exposed field to solve** my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have marked the exposed filter as required.

Uncheck the "Required" checkbox right below the "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 

This is what I thought but all my filters are not required...